# Can you download files from a server with RESTApi

Tags: node.js, rest

I was wondering if you can call create a GET request on a RESTApi server to download a file. For example if i called a `GET` request to  `http://<IP>/storage/download/:filePath/` it would download that file. I am writing the RESTAPi in nodejs.

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const root = {}

//for this example say filepath = api%2Fstorage%2FImages%2FtestPhoto.png or api/storage/Images/testPhoto.png

 

router.get("/download/:filePath", (req, res, next) => {
  var filePath = req.params.filePath;
  filePath = decodeURIComponent(filePath)

  res.sendFile(filePath);
  // this is what im questioning. If i use this will it send the file? if so how will i download it on the front end?
})
```

Comment: Can you download files on the Web? If so, you can in a REST architecture as well ... If you are looking for someone to post you code, post what you have tried so far first, this will probably increase the likelihood of receiving more valuable answers

Comment: @RomanVottner I just edited the post and added more code. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If the server directory is this

```
main.js
 └── storage
      └── Image
           └── testPhoto.png
```

Add this,

```
router.use('/api/storage', express.static('storage'));
```

Then request it from frontend. GET /api/storage/Image/testPhoto.png

Comment: This worked for displaying the image. How can i create a download link? I tried: 
`<a href="<getUrl>" download>click here to download!</a>` but it just opened the image in a new window.

Answer (score 0):

Express has a [helper](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download) for this to make life easier.

```
app.get('/download', function(req, res){
  const file = `${__dirname}/folder/download.csv`;
  res.download(file); // Set disposition and send it.
});
```